# Can we calculate van der Waals' constant a for the following case?

Tags: physical-chemistry, gas-phase-chemistry, van-der-waals-behavior

[image]

The given Z vs P curve for 1 mole of a gas at 400K starts at Z=1 & P=0.

The slope at the point when the curve again intersect Z=1 is 0.005. The critical temperature of the gas is 500K.

**My approach:**

From the [van der Waals'](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) equation,

$$(P+\frac{a}{V^2})(V-b)=RT$$

On expanding,
$$\frac{PV}{RT}=Z=1-\frac{a}{VRT}+\frac{Pb}{RT}+\frac{ab}{V^2RT}$$

And  $$ PV=ZRT  $$ $-(1)$

By both equations,
$$Z=1-\frac{a}{VRT}+\frac{Zb}{V}+\frac{ab}{V^2RT}$$ $-(2)$

Differentiating with respect to Z for
Equation (1)

$$ PV'+VP'=RT$$

Equation (2)

$$ 1= \frac{aV'}{V^2RT}+\frac{b}{V}-\frac{bV'}{V^2}-\frac{2abV'}{V^3RT}$$

& $$T_c=\frac{8a}{27Rb}$$

Now I am stuck, I don't even know if I am moving in the right direction because things are becoming too complex to solve.

Where,

a, b = [van der Waals' gas constants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_constants_(data_page))

Z = [Compressibility Factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility_factor)

V = Volume of gas when curve again intersects Z = 1

R = [Universal gas constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant)

T = 400K

$T_c$ = [Critical Temprature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/?redirect=no&title=Critical_temperature)

Comment: @Poutnik yes angle a pressure dependent and it is specific angle on the point when curve intersects Z=1.

Comment: I mean something else. For given pressure, angle depends on pressure unit. Tangens of angle is 1000x bigger for kPa than for Pa.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I couldn't edit that one because it is an image from web.

Comment: You need Z=f(p), not Z=(p,V(p)). But as you are interested in region near Z=1, you can do substitution V=RT/p.

Comment: Can you please explain briefly in the answer?

Comment: Does not $dZ/dP=b/RT$ ? As you know $T_c$ and the slope then you know $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @porphyrin, I think it's not because as you see in the equation 2. $Z$ depends on $V$ too, which is a variable. It this was true The $Z$ vs $P$ graph will left only a straight line as there's no variable in your slope.

Comment: You can use substitution V = ZRT/P, but it helps just partially, getting the implicit cubic function f(Z,P)=0.

Comment: @Siddarth, you are right, silly me! Try this, substitute $PV=RT$ and solve for $Z=0$ to get $P$, next  differentiate Z to get slope whose value you know and use Tc to connect a and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were going in the right direction, But I has an extra step.

You already had proved the following equations.

$$ PV'+VP'=RT-(1)$$$$ 1= \frac{aV'}{V^2RT}+\frac{b}{V}-\frac{bV'}{V^2}-\frac{2abV'}{V^3RT}-(2)$$$$T_c=\frac{8a}{27Rb}-(3)$$$$\frac{PV}{RT}=Z=1-\frac{a}{VRT}+\frac{Pb}{RT}+\frac{ab}{V^2RT}-(4)$$

Substituting values $T_c=500K$, $T=400K$, $R=0.08$ (it will make calculation easier), $P'= \frac{dP}{dZ} = \frac{1}{0.05}=200 $ (at POI) in equation $(1),(2),(3)$ gives,

$$ \frac{32V'}{V}+200V=32-(A)$$$$ 1= \frac{aV'}{32V^2}+\frac{b}{V}-\frac{bV'}{V^2}-\frac{abV'}{16V^3}-(B)$$$$\frac{a}{b}=135-(C)$$
Now, if you look at the equation $(4)$. If you you put $Z=1$

$$\frac{a}{VRT}=\frac{Pb}{RT}+\frac{ab}{V^2RT}$$

Canceling out $ \frac{1}{VRT} $ and Substituting $P=RT/V$ gives,

$$a=32b+\frac{ab}{V}⟹\frac{a}{b}=32+\frac{a}{V}⟹135=32+\frac{a}{V}$$

So,

$$\frac{a}{V}=103-(D)$$

So, we're done.

By equation $(A),(B),(C),(D)$,

$$a= \frac{46532}{2575}≈18.07$$ $$b=\frac{46532}{347625}≈0.134$$
$$V=\frac{46532}{265225}≈0.175$$
$$V'=-\frac{47648768}{2813772025}≈-0.017$$

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a mistake in the fifth expression. It should be written $$PV' + P'V = RT$$
Second, it is not clear what Siddharth is looking for. If he wants a way of calculating $a$ with other van der Wals parameters, the simplest way is to draw $a$ from the final formula giving the critical temperature :  $$\ce{a = \frac{27}{8}bRT_c}$$ Here the curve $Z(P)$ is not needed.

Comment: Actually b is unknown. But this gives the relation $\frac{a}{b}≈135$. That I've used.

Comment: Can you tell what is the mistake in fifth expression, So I could correct it.

Comment: @Siddharth. You have written $PV' + V'P = ...$ If this had been correct, it could have been rewritten $PV' + V'P = 2 PV'$. But, care ! The position of the second   "prime" is wrong. You should have written $PV' + P'V = ..$

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry that was typing mistake. How could I further proceed to the question?

Comment: What are you looking for ? What is the question ?

Comment: Sorry van der Waal**

Comment: @Siddharth "van der Waals"  :-)

Comment: No, no ! Please write van der Waals ! W A A L S ! With two A letters !

Comment: Yes, "van der Waals". My keyboard has auto correct problem.